Obtaining a Kinnersley null tetrad for Petrov type D spacetimes
I'm trying to apply the Newman-Penrose formalism to a spacetime I know is Petrov type D to calculate its Teukoulsky equation.
In the papers I've read, it is standard to use a Kinnersley null tetrad to apply the NP formalism. However, it is never explained how to obtain this tetrad or why we choose it.
I would like to know the importance of Kinnersley null tetrad in this context, if there is a method to obtain it given an arbitrary Petrov type D spacetime, and if there is any good resource to learn more about this subject.

In Kinnersley tetrad null vectors $l^\mu$ and $n^\mu$ of the NP formalism lie along the principal null directions (PND) of the Weyl tensor. Recall, that type D spacetime has two double PND.
Chandrasekhar's book The Mathematical Theory of Black Holes is the standard reference on the subject.

But what about the third vector from the tetrad? Will any null complex vector that is orthogonal to those two suffice?

I am not sure. Does your spacetime have Killing vector field with orbits orthogonal to PND (something like axial symmetry of Kerr)?

No, it does not.

Then you are outside the scope of Kinnersley's work. You can probably check papers like gr-qc/0601094 but those are for non-type D spacetimes so may not translate to your problem.
